# How to deal with Polylang and wp_update_post function?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have the following code to insert posts in wp_posts table using wp_insert_post function:

http://pasted.co/c3fcb315

I'm using Polylang for this CPT called "Property", posts must be set in two languages: Spanish and English. The insert part is working like a charm but I don't know how to deal with the update process (wp_update_post).

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

You are not passing the id in the first part of your loop:

```
if ( ! $propid ) {
        $post_args = array(
            //NEED ID TO UPDATE WITH WP_UPDATE_POST
            'post_title'   => $property['MLSNumber'],
```

Comment: I'm passing the ID in the else clause:

else {
    $post_args  = array(
 'ID'           => $propid->ID,
 'post_title'   => $property['MLSNumber'],
 'post_content' => $property['Remarks'],
        .
        .
        .
}

First block is for insert, the second is for update if post already exists. (I'm getting this data from the client server)